# How to join Path from multiple parts of different type in Rust?

Tags: rust

Documentation provides following example for joining paths:

```
use std::path::PathBuf;

let path: PathBuf = [r"C:\", "windows", "system32.dll"].iter().collect();
```

This works when all the components are strings. However, I am trying to write following function:

```
use std::path::PathBuf;
fn my_path<P: AsRef<Path>>(root: P, dir1: &str, dir2: &str, dir3: &str) -> PathBuf {
    [root, dir1, dir2, dir3].iter().collect()
}
```

The above obviously doesn't work. I know I can do series of nested joins, but that is, ..., more ugly.

Is there a way to join different path-like components in array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can cast them to dynamic `AsRef<Path>` objects:

```rust
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};
fn my_path<P: AsRef<Path>>(root: P, dir1: &str, dir2: &str, dir3: &str) -> PathBuf {
    [&root as &dyn AsRef<Path>, &dir1, &dir2, &dir3].iter().collect()
}
```

or just add the first different object with join:

```rust
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};
fn my_path<P: AsRef<Path>>(root: P, dir1: &str, dir2: &str, dir3: &str) -> PathBuf {
    root.as_ref().join([dir1, dir2, dir3].iter().collect::<PathBuf>())
}
```

Here it is on [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f3cd171d66baafbc741c4ac0669f3d63)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert them to `Path`s:

```rust
fn my_path<P: AsRef<Path>>(root: P, dir1: &str, dir2: &str, dir3: &str) -> PathBuf {
    [
        root.as_ref(),
        Path::new(dir1),
        Path::new(dir2),
        Path::new(dir3),
    ]
    .iter()
    .collect()
}
```

Or, if the list is long (but this may be less efficient):

```rust
fn my_path<P: AsRef<Path>>(root: P, dir1: &str, dir2: &str, dir3: &str) -> PathBuf {
    std::iter::once(root.as_ref())
        .chain([dir1, dir2, dir3].iter().map(Path::new))
        .collect()
}
```